# Image as planes option disappeared? Where is it

Tags: mesh, add-on

I have it enabled in the addons section, but it's not in my add mesh options, not under any option, see here[image]

where is it?

Answer (score 0):

i was in edit mode and didnt realize it. leaving edit mode brought the option back